# CRM interface cast in VB.NET throwing InvalidCastException

Tags: vb.net, casting, crm

I'm trying to cast the CRM interfaces OrganizationServiceProxy as IOrganizationService in VB.NET.

This code part is working in C#;

```
Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceProxy orgProxy = new Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceProxy(organizationUri, null, credentials, null);
Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IOrganizationService myService = (IOrganizationService)orgProxy;
```

But I need to write this in VB.NET and it's not working;

```
serviceProxy = New OrganizationServiceProxy(New Uri(uri), Nothing, credentials, Nothing)
Dim myService As Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IOrganizationService = TryCast(serviceProxy, IOrganizationService)
```

I also tried *DirectCast, CType* but they are also not working.

Comment: By not working what exactly do you mean; does your code throw an exception or merely not do what you want? Which line is failing?

Comment: sorry exception is that:Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceProxy' to type 'CRMServis.IOrganizationService'.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have your own IOrganizationService within the CRMServis project.

Try the following:

```
Dim orgProxy As New Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceProxy(organizationUri, Nothing, credentials, Nothing)
Dim myService As Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IOrganizationService = DirectCast(orgProxy, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IOrganizationService)
```

If you are working in a plugin or workflow, use the: "OrganizationServiceContext" instead.